# Index multiple, non-adjacent ranges in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to select multiple, non-adjacent ranges from a 1d numpy array (or vector).

Suppose:

```
>>> idx = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
array([82,  9, 11, 94, 31, 87, 43, 77, 49, 50])
```

This works, of course:

```
>>> idx[0:3]
array([82,  9, 11])
```

And this works to fetch via individual indices:

```
>>> idx[[0,3,4]]
array([82, 94, 31])
```

But what if I want to select the ranges `0:3`, and `7:`?

I've tried:

```
>>> idx[[0:3,7:]]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to generate them separately and concatenate?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to concatenate, either before or after indexing.  `np.r_` makes it easy

```
In [116]: idx=np.array([82,  9, 11, 94, 31, 87, 43, 77, 49, 50])
In [117]: np.r_[0:3,7:10]
Out[117]: array([0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9])
In [118]: idx[np.r_[0:3,7:10]]
Out[118]: array([82,  9, 11, 77, 49, 50])
```

`np.r_` expands the slices and concatenates them.

You can mix slices and lists:

```
In [120]: np.r_[0:3,7:10,[0,3,4]]
Out[120]: array([0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 4])
```

Concatenating before indexing is probably faster than after, but for 1d array like this, I don't think the difference is significant.

Comment: Note: I tried using np.r_ without fully specifying indexes, i.e. np.r_[:3,7:] and the result was very strange. Using it by fully specifiying start and end indexes (np.r_[0:3,7:10]) worked as expected.

Comment: @BlueCoder, In normal indexing, the `stop` value for `[7:]` can be deduced from the array/list that's indexed.  `r_` can't do that.  It looks like it treats the `7` as a `stop` rather than `start`.  An alternative would have been to raise an error.  Examine the `r_` code for details.  It's best to provide both `start` and `stop` when using `r_`.

Comment: @hpaulj And how would that work for a 2d array? Let 's say I want different non-adjacent row ranges specific to each column. How would that work?

Comment: @CodeNoob I asked a question about the case of the 2D array with non-adjacent row ranges and received a [pretty good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63380108/2464671).