# Numpy - select several continuous rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an EEG signal in a Numpy Array.
I sliced the Array, so i do have each channel of interest in an own array (x rows an 1 coloumn).

Now I want to select 1 second periods of this specific Array, but I just cant figure out how to do this in a single argument.

Now in Matlab i could do following:

```
eeg_short = eeg(13:20, 27:30, 44, 60:end],:);
```

Meaning that I do get the 13th to 20th, 27th to 30th ..... and 60th to the last row of each coloumn in this array.

How can I do this with Numpy?
I tried several commands, like:

```
fz_short = fz[[7084:7084+256, 15620:15630+256],:]
```

which returns that ":" is an invalid syntax...

Comment: What is `fz.shape`?

Comment: Use `numpy.r_`.

Comment: This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188620/index-multiple-non-adjacent-ranges-in-numpy) one